# Silverlight NumericUpDown: Set max character length, or validate against it?

Tags: silverlight, events, validation

I'm attempting to use the key up event to hijack the event and prevent two things. Anything but numeric keys or delete/back as well as once they hit a certain max of character length, inhibit the entry.

This solves the first validation portion, but I can't seem to figure out a way to prevent entry past a certain character length.

```
    private void numericFieldInputField_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.D0 || e.Key == Key.D1 || e.Key == Key.D2 || e.Key == Key.D3 || e.Key == Key.D4 || e.Key == Key.D5 ||
            e.Key == Key.D6 || e.Key == Key.D7 || e.Key == Key.D8 || e.Key == Key.D9 || e.Key == Key.NumPad0 || e.Key == Key.NumPad1 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad2 || e.Key == Key.NumPad3 || e.Key == Key.NumPad4 || e.Key == Key.NumPad5 || e.Key == Key.NumPad6 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad7 || e.Key == Key.NumPad8 || e.Key == Key.NumPad9 || e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete ||
            e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right || e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //show validation
        }
    }
```

When I check the length of the numeric updown's value, cast it to string and look at the length property at this point, the last character they entered won't register. Also, when I set e.Handled to true, it still enters the character into the input. I thought e.Handled = true would keep the UI from putting the character into the input?

Comment: As to why e.Handled = true isn't working, it's because the textbox control itself already eats the event before you get to it. In WPF, you can work around this with "Preview Events." Unfortunately, SL has no such facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a Validator. In the databinding you specify the validator you want, the framework takes care of the rest. Here's one good intro to the topic: [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335695.aspx)

Comment: i appreciate the suggestion and will look into that more in teh future but in this specific case, programmatically i'd like to be able to handle it right here if possible.

Comment: Have you tried binding the event handler to the keydown as opposed to the keyup event?